# Multiple Models in Single View in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Could somebody please provide an example of how to combine **15 models within one view**?
I can't use **Tuple** coz Tuple only support 4 model in One View... after 5 razor syntax not support..
So I used Dictionary  for List i can be done by Create view only but I can't save by each model...

in Controller Create View

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        try
        {            
             var model = new Dictionary<string, Model>()
            {
                { "table1", new validation.table1() },
                { "table2", new validation.table2() },
                { "table3", new validation.table3() },
                { "table4", new validation.table4()},
                { "table5", new validation.table5()},
                { "table6", new validation.table6()},
                { "table7", new validation.table7()},
                { "table8", new validation.table8()},
                { "table9", new validation.table9()},
                { "table10", new validation.table10()},
                { "table11", new validation.table11()},
                { "table12", new validation.table12()},
                { "table13", new validation.table13()},
                { "table14", new validation.table14() },
                { "table15", new validation.table15()}
            };
           return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A `Tuple` would never have worked anyway, and neither will a dictionary because you would not be (easily) able to create the correct `name` attributes to post back to your model. Create a view model representing want you want to display/edit

Comment: create partial views for each model

Comment: if this doesnt work for your scenario, create a custom class in models and use it in the view

Comment: Pls provide me with some example ....

Answer (score 0):

The key step is to create a class to model what you want your view to be able to work with, which is a type of class known as a *view model*. In your example, you'd like to use 15 objects. I'm not sure what type of object you want your "tables" to be so I'll just assume there's a class `Table` in your code somewhere which you can change accordingly to fit your specifications. Your view model would then contain 15 member variables of type `Table`:

```
public class TableViewModel
{
    public Table Table1 { get; set; }
    public Table Table2 { get; set; }
    public Table Table3 { get; set; }
    public Table Table4 { get; set; }
    public Table Table5 { get; set; }
    public Table Table6 { get; set; }
    public Table Table7 { get; set; }
    public Table Table8 { get; set; }
    public Table Table9 { get; set; }
    public Table Table10 { get; set; }
    public Table Table11 { get; set; }
    public Table Table12 { get; set; }
    public Table Table13 { get; set; }
    public Table Table14 { get; set; }
    public Table Table15 { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, it's now your job to create and populate an instance of that view model. I'm not sure quite exactly where your table objects are coming from so I'll just say that in my example I have 15 variables named 'table1', 'table2', etc.:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    TableViewModel model = new TableViewModel()
    {
        Table1 = table1,
        Table2 = table2,
        Table3 = table3,
        // ...
        Table15 = table15
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Finally, in your view, all you need to do is strongly type the view to your new view model.

```
@model TableViewModel

// Perform work with tables; each can be referenced
// as Model.Table1, Model.Table2, and so on.
```

That's all!

Comment: Thanks I'm trying like this Thanks Chase, Thanks  Stephen Muecke and toing_toing ... I will get back comments.....